# zoo object just inserted random rows when I tried cbind. What happened?

Tags: r, zoo

I am not sure what happened to my zoo object. I tried to bind another column to my zoo object and all of a sudden my index exploded. Here is what I tried:

```
dates.zoo <- zoo(data.frame(val=seq(1:121)), order.by = seq.Date(as.Date('2018-12-01'), as.Date('2019-03-31'), "days"))
cbind(dates.zoo, ti=as.character(1:nrow(dates.zoo)))
           val  ti  
1970-01-02 <NA> 1   
1970-01-03 <NA> 2   
1970-01-04 <NA> 3   
1970-01-05 <NA> 4   
...
```

Where did 1970 come from? It was never in the original zoo object (before I bound a new column)

Comment: I do not think you can have both Date and character class in the same zoo object, this leads to problems with indexing I think.

Comment: I agree with you but you'd think it would just error out - not completely corrupt itself

Comment: `dates.zoo$ti <- 1:nrow(dates.zoo)` this should work

Comment: The second object has no index, so zoo does its best to convert 1, 2, 3, to an index. You can check that `zoo::as.Date(1) = `"1970-01-02".

Comment: I get `Warning message: Index vectors are of different classes: Date integer` when I run your code

Comment: @dipetkov - I think you may have something here - how should the second parameter look like for the `cbind(...)` to work?

Comment: @Chabo - I know that not using `as.character(...)` fixes it but WHY does it fix it? if dipetkov is right, how does it MAGICALLY know the index of that column (if the values are numeric) but DOESN'T KNOW the index if the column values are char?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit easier to see if we make the example smaller.  The code below coerces the second argument to a `zoo` class object giving `zoo(as.character(11:13), 1:3)` and then it coerces the index class of the second argument (`integer`) to be of the same index class as the first argument (`Date`).  The warning message does warn that different index classes are being used.

`cbind.zoo` does have special processing to handle plain vectors but only if they are of the same type as the core data of the zoo object. Had a plain vector been used of the *same type* as the core data of the first argument, i.e. both `numeric`, it would have worked as desired.  The commented out line labelled `correct` shows this.

```
library(zoo)
dates.zoo <- zoo(data.frame(val= 1:3), as.Date('2019-01-03') + 0:2)
# cbind(dates.zoo, ti=11:13) # correct
cbind(dates.zoo, ti=as.character(11:13)) # incorrect
```

which gives:

```
           val  ti  
1970-01-02 <NA> 11  
1970-01-03 <NA> 12  
1970-01-04 <NA> 13  
2019-01-03 1    <NA>
2019-01-04 2    <NA>
2019-01-05 3    <NA>
Warning message:
In merge.zoo(..., all = all, fill = fill, suffixes = suffixes, retclass = "zoo",  :
  Index vectors are of different classes: Date integer
```

Also note:

```
as.Date(1:3)
## [1] "1970-01-02" "1970-01-03" "1970-01-04"
```

Comment: So how would I append this character column to the existing zoo object so it behaves like adding a column to a data.frama?

Comment: The thing that makes this very confusing is that cbind() is supposed to bind a column to something. As an end user you’re not expecting the rows to be changing. I accidentally saw the rows changed but I could have easily missed it. That behavior is something I would expect the merge() function to do but not cbind()

Comment: I think this should be an error case as practically this kind of functionality should be done in a merge()

Comment: The basic misconception here is that zoo objects are like data.frames..  In fact, zoo objects are like ts objects and are constructed from matrices or plain vectors with an index attribute.  You can't mix numeric and character in ts objects or in matrices and that goes for zoo objects too.  (There is a lot of documentation that comes with the zoo package including several vignettes that you might want to go through and this is all explained.)

Comment: Thank you. I will read the vignettes more thoroughly. I'm not a big RTFM guy. This is what makes R unique from all the traditional programming languages that I use.

Comment: You seem to believe that data.frames are the natural basis for this but that is not how base R works.. In base R ts class, not data.frame class, is the basis for time series and zoo is used for time series.  zoo does work very much like ts and was designed to be a natural extension of ts to irregularly spaced series.  The zoo Design vignette discusses at length the philosophy of of zoo making it explicit.

Comment: I started another topic trying to decipher the difference between ts/zoo and data.frame as you are correct, I don't clearly see when I would use one v. the other: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142766/data-frame-or-ts-zoo-object